# How to copy lines above the selected line in Vim

Tags: vim, editor

I want to copy N lines above the selected position. `yNy` works for copying the below N lines.

What is the command for **copy N line above** the selected position?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`yNk` will copy the line you're on and the N preceding lines.

Comment: technically, it doesn't answer the question, of course. It is probably yhe most 'vimmy' answer (in that it focuses on normal mode)

Answer (score 4):

Or, use `:<range>yank` (see `:he range` for all possible uses of *range*)

```
:-3,-1y
```

this does precisely what you ask: yank only (e.g. 3) lines *before* the current line. You could

```
:-1y
:-2y
```

to yank *just* the previous (or pre-previous) line etc...

```
:1,-1y
```

to yank everything till the last line

```
:1,.y
```

for that including the current line (of course, you could do that with `ygg`)